# ASP looping through form elements times out

Tags: asp-classic

We are having an issue with ASP being very slow to loop through the elements of a form. The form created is simply a list of names and checkboxes (21 in our example). We then want to loop through the form elements and work out which checkboxes were ticked.

This routine creates the form, and is instant:

```
<%
  y = 0
  do while y <= ubound(overdueArray,2)%>
  <tr>
  <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
  <input type="hidden" name="employeeID<%=y%>" id="employeeID<%=y%>" value="<%=overdueArray(2,y)%>">
  <td align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-color:<%=session.Contents("PageTitleBorder")%>;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;">
  <%response.Write(overdueArray(0,y)&" "&overdueArray(1,y))%></td>
  <td align="center" style="border-width:1px;border-color:<%=session.Contents("PageTitleBorder")%>;border-left-style:solid;border-bottom-style:solid;border-right-style:solid;">
  <input type="checkbox" id="remind<%=y%>" name="remind<%=y%>" value="sendReminder<%=y%>">
  </td>                
  <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <%y = y + 1
  loop
%>
```

This code then hangs, or times out, with just 21 items on the screen:

```
x = 0
do while x <= request.Form("total")
if request.Form("remind"&x) <> "" then
                response.Write("test") 
end if                    
x = x + 1
loop
```

I'm not the developer and have no knowledge of ASP, this is for my colleague who isn't on SO yet.

Any ideas or advice, please?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, after struggling with this for hours, we resolved it. We put `request.Form("total")` into a session variable first (its a hidden form element) and check the variable instead of the form element each time in the loop. This resolved the issue.

Comment: Hours? Looks more like 6 minutes.

Comment: Heh. We'd struggled for so long that I turned to SO in my hour of need. Predictably, minutes after doing so, the web dev came up trumps.